# What's the proper way to share via Intent.createChooser

Tags: android, android-intent

The problem is I have an article that want to share to other apps, and I want to let the user to choose which app to share to. What I want to share is basically:

1. the title of the article
2. the URL of the article
3. the article content as HTML
4. the URL with some extra text (such as '**http://foo.com/article share from #FooApp**')

All of these fields are optional, but I want to share at least one of them.

Such as when share via SMS or twitter, I want to set the content to part 4. when share via Facebook, I want to set 1, 2, 3 together. And when share via email, I want to set subject as 1 and message as 4.

I know (correct me if I'm wrong) every target intent receiver has it's own logic to pick up the fields it needed. So I want to provide as much information as possible and I wrote the following code:

```
String message = article.getURL() + " #FooApp";
Intent intent = new Intent().setData(Uri.parse(article.getURL())
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, article.getTitle())
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, article.getHTML())
            .putExtra("sms_body", message)
            ...
            .setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share to"));
```

But the problem is, it seems like a trick between setData, putExtra, setType.

For some apps appear in the chooser dialog, when I choose, the confirm share window (of that app) display nothing that I set to the intent. (for some other apps they just say failed to fetch resource)

For the `putExtra` part, when I add or remove some `putExtra` code, the target intent receivers diff a lot than I expected.

So the question is: am I doing it the wrong way? Are there some guideline for this problem?

Comment: you must make chooser dialog yourself. then you can get the user want to share with what

Comment: But what if user want to share to an app that I don't know?